# Create Excel spreadsheet using the criteria from another table in MS Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I need some help with Ms Access VBA and Excel. I have two tables:

**t_Customer**

```
- CustomerID
- CustomerName
- CustomerAccnt
```

**t_Orders**

```
- OrderID
- Desc
- PartNo
- Amount
- Disc
- Date
- CustomerID
```

I need to create Excel file for each customer, including the orders details and customer details as well. Each file should be called "Transactions for .xls" My thought is to take each customer from the customer table in a loop, match the information from the orders table, create a temporary table, and export to Excel.

I don’t know how to do this, any help or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right lines. I would do something like this (presto code but should work)

```
Dim Db as DAO.Database
Dim Rst as DAO.Recordset

Set Rst = Db.OpenRecordset ("SELECT Customer_ID, Customer_name FROM t_Customer")
With Rst
    Do Until .Eof
        Db.CreateQueryDef "qryTemp_query", _
            "SELECT blah FROM t_Order WHERE Customer_ID=" & !Customer_ID.Value
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel97, _
            "qryTemp_query", "C:\Transactions for " & !Customer_name.Value
        Db.QueryDefs.Delete "qryTemp_query"
        .MoveNext
    Loop
End With
Rst.Close
Db.Close
```

Comment: @User594082 please consider marking this answer as accepted. Click the little check mark below the up/down arrows at the top left of this answer.